# Windows single signon for MS SQL Server database access from a Java web application

Tags: sql-server, spring, windows, tomcat, single-sign-on

We have a Java web application using spring, hibernate and MS SQL Server database(s) deployed on Tomcat server. The application is available to users 
in the intranet in a windows domain environment. We have a requirement that when a windows loggedin user accesses this application in the browser, we want to login that user into our application and then we need to get connection from the MS SQL Server database using the same authentication information that we get from the domain controller/Active Directory for that particular user so that the user can access only those databases/tables where (s)he has rights as the databse rights are already set based on the domain account of the users in the database server.

The question is: Is it easily doable specially the second part to get database connection from MS SQL Server? If so what are the possible solution(s)?